# Ayuda en NAVIGATION DRAWER - botón y mostrar items

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, supportmapfragment

Hice un navigation drawer y me eh quedado sin hacer nada por que me sale error, así es que tengo dos preguntas que hacer:

1.- al inicio oculte lo item del navigation y todo bien pero después en un fragmento después de haberme logeado quiero que me aparezcan nuevamente los demás item que oculte... como hago, utilice este código para ocultarlo
esto es en el Activity_main:

M_Menu =navigationView.getMenu();

```
    MenuItem target = M_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_sistemas);
    target.setVisible(false);

    MenuItem aa = M_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_logistica);
    aa.setVisible(false);

    MenuItem bb = M_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_calidad);
    bb.setVisible(false);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- En un fragmento eh añadido un botón y al darle clic en este quiero que muestre otro fragmento... pero no lo llama me genera error @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        pasar=inflater.inflate ( R.layout.frg_sistemas, container, false );
        login=(Button)pasar.findViewById ( R.id.btnlog );

```
    login.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        //FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        //FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            logeo fragment = new logeo();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.FragmentLogin,  fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

        }
    } );

    return pasar;
}

private FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    return null;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He intentado aplicar esto que comentas al nuevo nagitation drawer que monta el propio AS pero no funciona,tuve practicamente el mismo problema que comentas,como normalmente al poner el navigation drawer poner un boton que llame a uno de sus fragmentos o items es repetitivo poca gente lo hace y no encuentro en ningun sitio como hacerlo ya que el paso a otro fragment no es el mismo codigo.Yo quiero hacerlo porque todavia hay usuarios que cuando cogen tu app quieren poder acceder a los menus desde el mismo home

Comment: Hola, yo le cree un public void en mi fragmento y ahi puse visibles los item, y en el Activity principal solo lo jale, instanciando en la parte superor el fragemento asi: Frg_Logeo frg_logeo; y despues lo llamé frg_logeo.Cargar_Acceso(); cuando me logeo y acceso ahi me muestra nuevamente los item que quiero, a mi me salio, espero te salga a ti tambien . Suerte :)

Comment: Cesar si supiera como hacerlo pondria el codigo tal cual para ayudar claro que si.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema, que me ocurro a mi, aquí les dejo la respuesta :)

En su actividad principal llamar al Menú que llama a los `Item`:
 Menu `M_Sie_Menu`;

y en la misma clase donde esta `OnCreate()`, llamar a uno por uno y ponerlo así:

```
M_Sie_Menu =navigationView.getMenu();

MenuItem nombre= M_Sie_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_**tu item**);
nombre.setVisible(true);

MenuItem nombre= M_Sie_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_**tu item**);
nombre.setVisible(false);
```

y si quieres activarlo enn alguna de tus clases por medio de un boton:

lo mismo (lo instancias arriba) y dentro del boton pones el mismo codigo pero esta vez en SetVisible (true);